# Units in curved spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, hamiltonian, dirac-equation

The line element has units of length squared
\begin{align*}
ds^2 = g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu
\end{align*}
So in general relativity there are two conventions. First we can define the coordinates $x^\mu$ to be of the unit length. Otherwise we can define dimensionless coordinates and shift the unit length squared to the metric coefficiants $g_{\mu\nu}$ as discussed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/638104/how-are-units-handled-general-relativity-how-are-units-handled-in-curvilinear-c).

My question is the following. If I choose the coordinates to be dimensionless
\begin{align*}
(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)
\end{align*}
and have a look at the curved dirac equation
\begin{align*}
(i\hbar\gamma^\mu\nabla_\mu-mc)\Psi=0
\end{align*}
I can rearrange it and use the definition of the covariant derivative
\begin{align*}
\nabla_\mu\Psi = (\partial_\mu+\Omega_\mu)\Psi
\end{align*}
to get the schrödinger form
\begin{align*}
i\hbar\partial_0\Psi = H\Psi =: E\Psi
\end{align*}
if the Hamiltonian $H$ does not depent on $x^0$. But since $x^0$ is dimensionless the unit of $E$ is not Joule (it is Joule seconds) as it should be since I'd like to identify the eigenvalue $E$ of $H$ with the energy of the system. How can one fix this unit problem?